# How do I install BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am running Windows 8. When I run the command:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

I get the following error (it also fails to connect 4 more times).

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036BE3F0>: Failed to establish a new connec
tion: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine ac
tively refused it')': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
```

Comment: `pip install bs4`

Comment: Hi @joumaico, thanks for taking the time to reply. Your suggestion gives the same error as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

This might be firewall issue. Could you try this:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 --trusted-host
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply to me. It turns out the work firewall was blocking it.

Comment: Was it helpful?